# Finding the distribution of '1' in rows/columns from a parity-check matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, optimization, constraints, nonlinear-optimization

My question this time concerns the obtention of the degree distribution of a LDPC matrix through linear programming, under the following statement:

[image]

My code is the following:

```
function [v] = LP_Irr_LDPC(k,Ebn0)

options = optimoptions('fmincon','Display','iter','Algorithm','interior-point','MaxIter', 4000, 'MaxFunEvals', 70000);
fun = @(v) -sum(v(1:k)./(1:k));

A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [0, ones(1,k-1)];
beq = 1;
lb = zeros(1,k);
ub = [0, ones(1,k-1)];
nonlcon = @(v)DensEv_SP(v,Ebn0);
l0 = [0 rand(1,k-1)];
l0 = l0./sum(l0);

v = fmincon(fun,l0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon,options)
end
```

#### Definition of nonlinear constraints:

```
function [c, ceq] = DensEv_SP(v,Ebn0)

% It is also needed to modify this function, as you cannot pass parameters from others to it. 

h = [0 rand(1,19)];
h = h./sum(h); % This is where h comes from

syms x;
X = x.^(0:(length(h)-1));
R = h*transpose(X);

ebn0 = 10^(Ebn0/10);
Rm = 1;
LLR = (-50:50);
p03 = 0.3;
LLR03 = log((1-p03)/p03);
r03 = 1 - p03;
noise03 = (2*r03*Rm*ebn0)^-1;
pf03 = normpdf(LLR, LLR03, noise03);
sumpf03 = sum(pf03(1:length(pf03)/2));

divisions = 100;

Aj = zeros(1, divisions);
rho = zeros(1, divisions);
xj = zeros(1, divisions);
k = 10; % Length(v) -> Same value as in 'Complete.m'

for j=1:1:divisions
    xj(j) = sumpf03*j/divisions;
    rho(j) = subs(R,x,1-xj(j));
    Aj(j) = 1 - rho(j);
end

c = zeros(1, length(xj));
lambda = zeros(1, length(Aj));
for j = 1:1:length(xj)
    lambda(j) = sum(v(2:k).*(Aj(j).^(1:(k-1))));
    c(j) = sumpf03*lambda(j) - xj(j);
end

save Almacen
ceq = [];
%ceq = sum(v)-1;
end
```

This question is linked to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42821585/mackay-algorithm-fill-up-a-matrix-with-ones-and-zeros-from-degree-distribution). My problem is that I need that each element from vectors `v` and `h` resulting from this optimization problem is a fraction of `x/N` and `x/(N(1-r)` respectively.

How could I ensure that condition without losing convergence capability?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with one possible solution, at least for vector `h`, within the function `DensEv_SP`:

```
function [c, ceq] = DensEv_SP(v,Ebn0)

% It is also needed to modify this function, as you cannot pass parameters from others to it. 

k = 10; % Same as in Complete.m, desired sum of h
M = 19; % Number of integers
h = [0 diff([0,sort(randperm(k+M-1,M-1)),k+M])-ones(1,M)];

h = h./sum(h);

syms x;
X = x.^(0:(length(h)-1));
R = h*transpose(X);

ebn0 = 10^(Ebn0/10);
Rm = 1;
LLR = (-50:50);
p03 = 0.3;
LLR03 = log((1-p03)/p03);
r03 = 1 - p03;
noise03 = (2*r03*Rm*ebn0)^-1;
pf03 = normpdf(LLR, LLR03, noise03);
sumpf03 = sum(pf03(1:length(pf03)/2));

divisions = 100;

Aj = zeros(1, divisions);
rho = zeros(1, divisions);
xj = zeros(1, divisions);
N = 20; % Length(v) -> Same value as in 'Complete.m'

for j=1:1:divisions
    xj(j) = sumpf03*j/divisions;
    rho(j) = subs(R,x,1-xj(j));
    Aj(j) = 1 - rho(j);
end

c = zeros(1, length(xj));
lambda = zeros(1, length(Aj));
for j = 1:1:length(xj)
    lambda(j) = sum(v(2:k).*(Aj(j).^(1:(k-1))));
    c(j) = sumpf03*lambda(j) - xj(j);
end

save Almacen
ceq = (N*v)-floor(N*v);
%ceq = sum(v)-1;
end
```

As above stated, there is no longer any problem with vector `h`; nevertheless the way I defined `ceq` value seemed to be insufficient to make the optimization work out (the problems with `v` have not diminished at all). Does anybody know how to find the solution?

Comment: Is this the solution? It looks like you are asking another question there at the end.